# Ionic 3 Search Filter Using Parse Data

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a search bar that searches for the users' input based on the name of a city.
On my HTML page, the names of the cities is already listed, but users have the option to search for a specific city too.
The names of the cities come from my database in Parse.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="searchCities($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Here is my .ts code, where `citiesTotal` is a variable that contains an array containing data from Parse about the cities:

```
searchCities(event) {

    var val = event.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.citiesTotal= this.citiesTotal.filter((city) => {
        console.log(city.name);
        return (city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
}
```

My console log line successfully retrieves the names of the cities once I click on the search bar. However the search bar itself does not filter any of the city names.

**[UPDATE]**

I thought I would include some more code to help sort this problem out, as suggested by @SergeyRudenko...

This is my .ts code, and includes the code where I pull data in from my provider file. `CityServ` is my provider file.

```
constructor (private cityService: CityServ) {

    //this successfully retrieves the data I need
    if (this.cityService.all().length == 0) {
      this.cityService.getCities().then((success) => {
        this.cities = this.cityServ.all();
        this.citiesTotal = this.cities;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error!');
      });
    } else {
      this.cities = this.cityService.all();
      this.citiesTotal = this.cities;
    }
}

searchCities(event) {

    var val = event.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.citiesTotal= this.citiesTotal.filter((city) => {
        console.log(city.name);
        return (city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant code in my .html file:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="searchCities($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{city.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Did you try this guide? https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes I did! I changed my code to fit what the example on the site states, but I am still getting the same error. As in, the search bar does not filter any items.

Comment: Ok can you take your code and use stackblitz.com to create reproducable example? Or just share full code that is relevant

Comment: @SergeyRudenko just added!

Comment: Awesome, i will check and share my answer in few hours.

Comment: can you share cityService.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so ideally you should also share your cityService provider code since that can have additional context which is not seen from the shared code.

Now with the code you shared there are 3 issues that I found:

1st particular issue in the searchCities method - specifically in this line:

```
this.citiesTotal= this.citiesTotal.filter((city) => {...}
```

Basically every time user types in search box you reassign this.citiesTotal to its filtered subset. While ideally you should keep what you render to user as search result and your original list of cities separate.

Try this:

```
searchCities(event) {

    var val = event.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      // here assign to "cities" instead of "citiesTotal":
      this.cities = this.citiesTotal.filter((city) => {
        return (city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
}
```

Now your ts code should have separation:
- during initialization in constructor you assign data to both of the variables (cities and citiesTotal) but then based on user actions you should only apply changes to the variables "cities".

2nd issue is that you are missing logic on user's reset of search. See [official doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) for searchbar there is a special listener for that: (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)". In your ts code you should have something like this for reset:

```
resetSearch(event) {
    this.cities = this.citiesTotal;
}
```

And then in your template you will need to add (ionCancel)="resetSearch($event)".

3rd issue I see in your template is that your binding is not pointing to correct items:

```
<ion-searchbar showCancelButton="true" (ionInput)="searchCities($event) (ionCancel)="resetSearch($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
    // here ensure your ngFor is pointing to the right var:
    <ion-item *ngFor="let city of cities">
        {{city.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Try to fix all the three issues and let me know if you struggle with it.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!